# FlinkKafkaConsumer is not working with consumer group on 2 nodes

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I use FlinkKafkaConsumer with two consumer(2 nodes) and two partitions. But the two consumers receive the same message regardless of which partitions it is pushed to.

```
public static SourceFunction<EventBase> createEventSource(Config config) throws IOException {
        String sourceType = config.get(EVENTS_SOURCE_TYPE);
        EventsSource.Type eventsSourceType = EventsSource.Type.valueOf(sourceType.toUpperCase());

        switch (eventsSourceType) {
            case KAFKA:
                String kafkaBootstrapServers = config.get(SOURCE_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
                String kafkaGroupId = config.get(SOURCE_KAFKA_GROUPID);
                String topic = config.get(SOURCE_KAFKA_TOPIC);

                Properties properties = new Properties();
                properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", kafkaBootstrapServers);
                properties.setProperty("group.id", kafkaGroupId);

                FlinkKafkaConsumer<EventBase> kafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(topic, new SimpleSyslogEventSchema(), properties);
                kafkaConsumer.setStartFromGroupOffsets();
                return kafkaConsumer;
           }
}



        return env.addSource(EventsSource.createEventSource(config))
                .name(config.get(EVENTS_SOURCE_NAME))
                .setParallelism(1)
                .startNewChain();
```

Can you suggest me to help solve this problem?